# How do I create a list of all possible anagrams of a word in javascript?

Tags: javascript, anagram

How do I create a list of all possible anagrams of a word in javascript?If this question has already been asked please direct me to the answer?

Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232295/is-there-any-pre-built-method-for-finding-all-permutations-of-a-given-string-in-j

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go: [Anagrams finder in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909449/anagrams-finder-in-javascript)

I'm not sure whether that's the exact same problem as yours, but there look to be a few good solutions in the answers.

**EDIT:** Actually, this is what you need: [Is there any pre-built method for finding all permutations of a given string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232295/is-there-any-pre-built-method-for-finding-all-permutations-of-a-given-string-in-j)

Comment: @Town Im not trying to find or compare anything, I just need all the anagrams sorted in an array

Comment: Do they need to be valid words? Eg: for `town`, you'd get `nowt` and `wont`, but not `wnot` ?

Comment: @Town It doesnt have to be valid words,just all possible anagrams sorted like this abcd,abdc,acbd,acdb,adbc,adcb...... Im only bother about the sorting not the validity,thanks

Comment: @manraj82: So what you actually want are all permutations of characters of a given set.

Comment: @Felix yes thats what im looking for.. you could say im looking for an anagram creator

Comment: @manraj82: You could say that... although what Felix says is probably more correct as an anagram is _a word, phrase or name formed by rearranging the letters of another_.

Comment: @town sorry,is that not what i asked? Apologies if the question is confusing

Comment: @town Is this question still a duplicate of "Anagrams finder in javascript"?

Comment: @manraj82: No, it's a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232295/is-there-any-pre-built-method-for-finding-all-permutations-of-a-given-string-in-j) :)

Comment: The link you posted only works for 3 letter words. I would say its not a sufficient answer (+1 for link though). Another critical missing step/suggestion is sorting out the fake words checking against something like a prefix trie. http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=120